# Passing functions through props from parent states in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

So this may be a bit confusing so I'll try to simplify it as best I can.

I have my state which holds an array of objects in my parent Component `App.js`. Here's an example of an object.

```
{
category: "sample category",
API: "API URL",
active: function()
}
```

In my child component `Category.js`, I have that array passed through a prop. The child renders a `ul` and then maps over the array to create an `li` for each category. Each list item should have an onClick event that triggers the associated `active: function()` in the object.

For some reason this isn't working. If I run a test where the function is a simple `console.log("success")` it's no problem. So the list item is picking up the function and running it fine through my props.

This leads me to believe that it's the actual function which I'm running that's the issue. The function I'm trying to run is this (located in `App.js`)

```
function() {
  this.setState({categoryActive: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20&category=11"});
  this.setState({showQuestions: true});
}
```

Those states being set are in `App.js`, and the function is also located in `App.js`, but is being run through a prop by a list item in `Category.js`. Is this my problem? Can I not adjust the state of `App.js` through function run in a child component?

---

EDIT: Here's a lot more code to help figure out the solution.

The actual error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at catMovies (App.js:71)

App.js:71 is `this.setState({categoryActive: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20&category=11"});` of my `catMovies()` function.

My `App.js` constructor

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  showCategories: false,
  showQuestions: false,
  isQuestionLoaded: false,
  categories: [{
    category: "movies",
    API: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=11",
    active: this.catMovies
  }, {
    category: "sports",
    API: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=21",
    active: this.catSports
  }, {
    category: "books",
    API: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=10",
    active: this.catBooks
  }, {
    category: "videogames",
    API: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=15",
    active: this.catVideogames
  }, {
    category: "general",
    API: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=9",
    active: this.catGeneral
  }, {
    category: "everything",
    API: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10",
    active: this.catEverything
  }],
  categoryActive: "",
  questionNumber: 0,
  questionTotal: null,
  correct: [],
  score: 0,
  showFinal: false,
  testState: "test"
};
this.showCategories = this.showCategories.bind(this);
this.showQuestions = this.showQuestions.bind(this);
this.catMovies = this.catMovies.bind(this);
}
```

Here is the actual function in `App.js`:

```
catMovies() {
  this.setState({categoryActive: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20&category=11"});
  this.setState({showQuestions: true});
}
```

Here is the return from `App.js` that calls the child compenent:

```
<Categories categoryList={ this.state.categories } onClick={ this.catMovies } />
```

And finally, here is the map in the child component that uses all this:

```
const categoryListItems = this.props.categoryList.map(cat =>
  <a href="#questionsContainer" key={cat.category + "link"}>
    <li onClick={cat.active} key={cat.category}>
      {cat.category}
    </li>
  </a>
);
```

Comment: You need to post more code of parent and child component.

Comment: @Prakashsharma I've added a lot more code in an edit. Thanks

Comment: i doubt that storing a function in the state is a good practice. i would conditionally pass the handler by its category, instead of storing it in the state.

Comment: @Sagivb.g Yes, not sure why I thought storing it in the state was a good idea when I could just define the array in a variable in my render. That seems to have fixed the error. Now I just need to figure out how to make sure my state change has taken effect before rendering :S

Thanks!

Comment: technically you can store it but your binding is wrong (see my answer for  clarity and examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the binding of the handler.
Instead of overriding the handler like you are doing in the constructor, you should do it directly inside your state initialization:

```
this.state = {
  showCategories: false,
  showQuestions: false,
  isQuestionLoaded: false,
  categories: [{
    category: "movies",
    API: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=11",
    active: this.catMovies.bind(this) // <-- you need to bind here
  },
 //...
```

Here is a running example with both patterns, note how the `turnOff` handler will throw the same error as you get:

```js
const LightBall = ({ on }) => {
  return (
    <div>{`The light is ${on ? 'On' : 'Off'}`}</div>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lightOn: false,
      toggle: this.toggleLight.bind(this), // this will work
      turnOff: this.turnOff // this will not work
    };
    this.turnOff = this.turnOff.bind(this);
  }

  toggleLight(){this.setState({ lightOn: !this.state.lightOn })};

  turnOff() { this.setState({ lightOn: false }) };

  render() {
    const { lightOn, toggle, turnOff } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle Light</button>
        <button onClick={turnOff}>Turn Off</button>
        <LightBall on={lightOn} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: i assume you are referring to my comment. if so, i didn't say moving the array out of the `state`  but moving the handlers out of the state. it is best to store serializable data, not mandatory but preferred.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably caused by the fact that in this function

```
function() {
  this.setState({categoryActive: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20&category=11"});
  this.setState({showQuestions: true});
}
```

`this` is referred to the class in which the function is called.

You could fix this by binding the function to the `App` component before passing the array to the child by using `bind()` (see more here https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

or you might instead use an arrow function if you define it in your `App` component for automatically bind it's scope to that component, so

```
{
category: "sample category",
API: "API URL",
active: () => {
    this.setState({categoryActive: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20&category=11"});
    this.setState({showQuestions: true});
  }
}
```

see more about arrow functions here https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#arrows-and-lexical-this

Comment: I don't believe this is the issue as I've bound this in my function. I've added a lot more code to the question to give people more information.